# Selecting parent of $(this) within function call

Tags: jquery, function, parent

I have an issue selecting the parent of $(this) when I call a function.  When I select the little 1 buttons, the buttons toggle as only one can be selected.  I have a function call to set the Big button as well.  I know I can set the state of the big button without calling a function however this is just the beginning of more reqs.

I thought adding the $(this).parent().prev().addClass('big_selected'); would do the trick however its not working for me, any suggestions on how to capture the element of the Big buttons and adding the specified class?

See demo here... http://jsfiddle.net/froze1906/aSyUE/1/

Comment: There no script in your jsFiddle, did you forget to put it in there?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the fiddle link, its updated.

Comment: `this` in your `setBig` function is the window, so then `$(this).parent()` is looking for the parent of the browser window, rather than the parent of the button that was clicked

Comment: @MrOBrian is right, use `setBig.call(this, evt)` to call setBig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need to accomplish what you want

```
$(':button[class*=small]').click(function(){ // <-- on all small button clicks
    $(this).parent().prev().addClass('big_selected'); // < -- add big class to closest big button
    $(this).addClass('small_selected'); // <-- add class to current clicked
    $(':button[class*=small]').not(this).removeClass('small_selected'); // <-- remove class from all but current clicked
    $(':button[class*=small]').not($(this).siblings().andSelf()).parent().prev().removeClass('big_selected'); // <-- remove class from Big that is not closest to current clicked
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aSyUE/3/

Comment: This short version looks really good too however what about if user clicks button 1 under Big 1 and clicks button 2 of Big 2 ... can both Big buttons stay highlighted?

Comment: So you want group to be separate?

Comment: If you can explain exactly what you want to happen between each one I ca help you @user1502434

Comment: When the small buttons are clicked the corresponding small and big button toggles on and off like radio buttons.  The only other function to add is the demo can have a Big 1 - small 1 and Big 3 - small 2 selected at the same time. Once this scenario exists, if user selects Big 2 - small 1, the Big 1 - small 1 buttons toggle off. I added another button in the demo, I attempted to keep the state of the buttons using globals  http://jsfiddle.net/froze1906/aSyUE/9/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14222/discussion-between-user1502434-and-wirey)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in your fiddle is changing:

```
setBig();
```

to:

```
setBig.call(this);
```

So that in the setBig function, `this` is the button that was clicked.

Your setBig function has an argument of `evt`, but you never use it. If you need to pass it, call your function as:

```
setBig.call(this, evt);
```

Also, you have two elements with the same id.  Element ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: In an effort to keep use of the global variables and the if statements here http://jsfiddle.net/froze1906/aSyUE/9/.  I am attempting to determine if a small button is clicked, save the value of $(this) to global variables. Within the if statements, I then do a comparison and attempt to remove class or add class accordingly.  Within the if (little_r == null && little_l == "button.small_l") I want to $('little_l').addClass('small_selected'); whereas 'little_l' is the global variable.  It does not appear to add the class.

Comment: don't wrap your variables in quotes. by doing `'little_l'` you are trying to use the string "little_l" as a selector, instead of using whatever object is stored in the variable `little_l`